# windows 8 mobile custom authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, push-notification, windows-phone-8, mpns

We are just starting to look at adding a Windows 8 Mobile application in addition to our website and the app needs to be restricted to authenticated users only.  Looking at the documentation it talks about authentication with Google, Facebook, Twitter, and Microsoft but we have our own authentication that is used on the site that we would be looking to use, perhaps exposed through a web service for the app.

We also want to send push notifications to users tied to their authenticated account on the website.

My question is can we implement a custom authentication for windows 8 phone and send push notifications to those authenticated users?  And if so can anyone suggest a good resource as after a fair amount of searching I can't find any examples of how this is achieved.

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
That's the best this question can be answered since it's not really a question for this forum.

For on example of an application take a look at how Chase app works on iPhone, I'm sure there are plenty other banking apps on other platforms that can push notifications to authenticated users for you to get an idea what can be done